# Access html ::shadow DOM element

Tags: html, dom, styles, shadow

I´m having a problem to access the element that is inside **shadow root**. I want to style h2 tag highlighted in red but I cannot seem to make it work. Can anybody suggest a way to access this DOM element?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the element in inspect element then go to the "copy" option and choose the option you need.
E.g. if you're using JavaScript "copy JS path".

You will end up with something like "document.querySelector("#notify-container")".

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. However, when I shorten the JS path to be able to apply with css, I get this: ```.cc-custom-collapsible .shadowRoot div > h2 {
  background-color: red;
}``` which unfortunately didnt work for me.

Comment: @Victoria you might want to look into the host selector then if you haven't already, hope that helps

Comment: I just found a great and simple solution - everything inside shadow part is accessible through ::part() pseudo. However, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: hi victoria, can you please elaborate on your solution, as its not very clear to me. If you could add a comprehensive answer to your question, im sure it will help many people out, cheers!